# attachInterrupt HIGH

Tags: arduino-due, interrupt, core-libraries

I'm trying to understand the implementation of `attachInterrupt`. For `LOW`, `CHANGE`, `RISING` and `FALLING` it seems simple enough; it sets some chip-specific registers and stores the given callback in `intFunc`, then invokes the callback from inside its own thin wrapper callback.

But the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt) says that on the Arduino Due, Zero and MKR1000, it can also accept `HIGH`. I can't find any reference to this in the code, and I can see that `HIGH` (= `0x01`) and `CHANGE` (= `1`) would be indistinguishable after preprocessing, so I can only assume a macro is involved somewhere, but I can't see one in the source.

How does the library implement this? Where is the code?

Comment: [`CHANGE` is defined as 2](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.6.6/hardware/arduino/sam/cores/arduino/wiring_constants.h#L53) in the SAM core.

Comment: @EdgarBonet ah, thank you. That explains it. And I see that the SAM version also checks which value is given inside `attachInterrupt`, unlike the AVR version which just passes it though. I'd got stuck on the AVR version since github's search seems incapable of seeing the SAM core.

Comment: For a reason I don't know, they recently moved that core to [a different repository](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-sam).